# Swapping Java lotto machine number input for dice roll instead to make like gambling machine

Tags: java

I asked this last night, but didn't get any answers most likely due to my poor formatting of the question so here I am reposting it in a more understandable context;

I made the Java Lotto program for my Java course, and then I was playing with the dice program I made from my Java book, and I was thinking I could make a gambling machine out of the lotto machine by replacing the number input with a dice roll instead. How would I go about swapping the number input for a dice roll? If the question doesn't make sense, let me know. Sorry for posting it twice in a short period of time.

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Scanner;

 class Lottery {

private final int lotteryNumbers[];

public Lottery() {

    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    lotteryNumbers = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
        lotteryNumbers[i] = Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) % 90;
    }
}

public class Dice {
    int die1;
    int die2;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random rand = new Random();
}

public int compareNumbers(int[] usersNumbers) {

    int match = 0;
    if (usersNumbers.length == lotteryNumbers.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
            if (usersNumbers[i] == lotteryNumbers[i]) {
                match++;
            }
        }
    }
     return match;
  }

public int[] getLotteryNumbers() {
    return lotteryNumbers;
}
  }

  public class LottoMachine11 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String again = "y";

    Lottery lottery = new Lottery();
    int lotteryNumbersCount = lottery.getLotteryNumbers().length;

    while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

        System.out.println("Lottery application\n");
        System.out.println("There are " + lotteryNumbersCount
                + " numbers in range of 0 through 9. "
                + "Try to guess all of them\n");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numbers[] = new int[lotteryNumbersCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("Enter number %d: ", i + 1));
            numbers[i] = kb.nextInt();
        }

        int match = lottery.compareNumbers(numbers);

        if (match == lotteryNumbersCount) {

            System.out.println("\nYou got all the numbers correct. You won the grand prize!");

        } else {

            System.out.println("Uh oh, you only got " + match + " number(s).");
            System.out.print("Play again? (y = yes)? ");
            again = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the dice roll class in for starters. I also added a loop, but I would like it to be a loop in an array, instead of a repeated print.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters you're gonna want to generate random dice values between 1 and 6, so you're Dice class should like something like this:

```
Dice {
    int die1;
    int die2;

    Random rand = new Random();

    //Generates random value between 1 and 6 for dice1 and dice2
    dice1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; 
    dice2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

followed by your getter methods to access the values for dice1 and dice2

Then ask the user to guess the dice values and compare the users input to the dice rolls. I'm not gonna code the whole thing for you, but I hope this pushes you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks Cody. It really does help, your explanations make sense. I'll be sure to work on it a bit.